# The .data attribute for a dataset in torchvision.datasets doesn't work for ImageFolder?

Tags: python, pytorch

I can access the training data set of an MNIST object like so:

```
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
trainset = MNIST(root='.', train=True, download=True)
print(trainset.data)
```

However, I'm not able to do the same using ImageFolder. Anybody know the equivalent for ImageFolder?

AttributeError: 'ImageFolder' object has no attribute 'data'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any.

Nowadays, everyone assumes that MNIST fits in memory, thus [it is preloaded to the `data` attribute](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/86500c84089e0d2e8fba398d4d3011558410a26f/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L93). However, this is usually not possible for `ImageDataset`s. Therefore, the [images are loaded on-the-fly](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/86500c84089e0d2e8fba398d4d3011558410a26f/torchvision/datasets/folder.py#L222) which means, no `data` attribute for them. You can access the image paths and labels using the `self.imgs` or `self.samples`.

Comment: Do you have an example for self.imgs/self.samples?

Comment: You can access those attributes (`.imgs` and `.samples`) in any instance of `ImageDataset`s.